# Correlation between a single HTTP request and multiple JMS messages

Tags: jms, correlation

Service A receives an HTTP request. If the request already has a request id the service will use it, otherwise the service will generate one. At this point the request id is guaranteed to exist and put into the logging context. Service A then produces 1-n JMS messages and sets their JMS correlation id header so that it matches the request id that was put into the logging context earlier. Every log entry generated by Service A while serving a particular HTTP request will have the same request id which is the expected and preferred behavior.

When consuming the messages Service B reads their correlation id and puts them into the logging context as request id. Service B then proceeds with the business logic. Every log entry generated by Service B will have the same request id for *all* messages consumed per HTTP request made to Service A which is expected but not the preferred behavior because it makes difficult if not impossible to tell what happened while consuming a particular message.

Sample log entries (simplified and sorted for clarity):

```
SERVICE  REQUEST ID  MESSAGE
-------  ----------  --------------------
A        request-id  Request received
A        request-id  Message #1 produced   <- JMS correlation id = request id
...
A        request-id  Message #n produced   <- JMS correlation id = request id
B        request-id  Message #1 received
B        request-id  Message #1 processed
...
B        request-id  Message #n received
B        request-id  Message #n processed
```

I'd like to be able to correlate *all* log entries from both Service A and B per HTTP request made to Service A (already achieved) but I'd like to be able to identify *all* log entries per message consumed by Service B as well (not achieved).

The only idea I could come up with was to make JMS correlation id headers set in Service A unique per message by concatenating the request id and a message specific id.

Sample log entries (simplified and sorted for clarity):

```
SERVICE  REQUEST ID    MESSAGE
-------  ------------  --------------------
A        request-id    Request received
A        request-id    Message #1 produced   <- JMS correlation id = request id + message specific id
...
A        request-id    Message #n produced   <- JMS correlation id = request id + message specific id
B        request-id-1  Message #1 received
B        request-id-1  Message #1 processed
...
B        request-id-n  Message #n received
B        request-id-n  Message #n processed
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

The issue is not language or JMS provider specific but if it helps I'm using Java and ActiveMQ. Service A is a native Spring application (non Spring Boot) whilst Service B is a Spring Boot application. Both Service A and B use Slf4+Logback as logging abstraction+framework.

Comment: There is an automatically generated unique message Id for each message, but it is not really a nice eye catcher for human log file investigations. What is it you don't like with your solution? It seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: If you don't want the additional message specific suffix in the same field, you can add a custom JMS message property.

Comment: @NineFriends As I stated in the question: "I'd like to be able to identify all log entries per message consumed by Service B as well". I'm aware of the message id and I agree that it's far from being ideal to use hence I'd obtain the "message specific id" from the body of the message instead, assuming that such id is available ofc.